# Anylogic model jobs to run simultaneously

Tags: anylogic

How can I model three jobs to always run simultaneously in Anylogic. Using code to model either how the agents are routed and processed or how the service block is coded.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Several options (there are even more)

## Wait block

You could use a `Wait` object before the critical flow elements.

Any agents "falls" into it and waits forever... Until you manually free it.

So upon agent entry into the `Wait` block, you can write some code to check "are my 2 other required agents in here already?".

If so, you can "free" them all using `myWaitBlock.free(agent)` and call it for the 3 agents that need to depart simultaneously.

## Batch

You can batch agents together and treat them as 1 batch until you unbatch them. Check the `Batch` and `Unbatch` blocks.

Comment: @Stuart and @ Benjamin, thanks. I tried using the batch/unbatch but did not get what I wanted. I wanted all three jobs to always start their process at exactly the same time. i had to use the match block and the function block. i wish there is another way to use less of blocks and more of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing process modelling (which it seems you are), this might be a misconception in how Service and Delay blocks work. Agents can be processed simultaneously (with what makes sense completely dependent on what you're modelling) if

- the Service block is using a resource pool (the norm); as many agents as there are free resources (given 1 resource per agent) will be processed 'simultaneously'.
- a Delay block has a capacity > 1 (in which case that's how many it can process 'simultaneously').

If you want something else (like one set of resources processing X agents 'simultaneously') then you'd use the techniques Ben suggested:

- A Batch --> Service --> Unbatch sequence if you always want to wait for X agents and process them together.
- A Wait block (and various other complexities) if you want resources to choose how many to process together up to a maximum (e.g., after they've finished processing Y agents, process the next Z agents where Z <= some maximum).

In general, you need to more clearly define what your 'processing logic' needs to be to know what the appropriate solution is.

Answer (score 0):

This is the screenshot of the function code I used
[image]